# How to get a user who created project in Asana with Asana API?

Tags: api, asana

I want to retrieve user (id, name) who created project in Asana with Asana Api.

Data returned from REST call in https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/{project-id} contains user object only in "followers" array, but these users are only... followers.

I tried with opt_fields parameter https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/{project-id}?opt_fields=created_by with no luck.

Any suggestions are welcome. Thnx.

Comment: Have you tried reading the Asana API documentation? Can you make your problem more specific?

Comment: @MathieuImbert yes, started with Asana API documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I work at Asana)

The creator is not currently exposed via the API. We may consider adding it in the future, however.

Comment: Is this still not supported? I hope it is. I'm doing a project integrated with Asana.. I need the project creator for permissions